# xsp2/mod_mono: Server error 500: xsp2 trys to load a dll which is not required for the current request

Tags: mono, mod-mono, xsp2

xsp2 shows a server error
"Could not load file or assembly 'cammWM' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'cammWM'
  at System.AppDomain.Load (...."

What I'm doing: I'm trying to access a test.aspx file which doesn't requires a reference to my cammWM.dll - just a simple hello world aspx file.
But I've placed a few additional files into the web root folder which contain references to the cammWM.dll. The bin folder with my cammWM.dll has been dropped for this test.

But I don't want the whole application to work, I just want to get my test.aspx running. And therefore, it doesn't need to compile the whole web application at first.

How can I convince XSP2/mod_mono to compile/load only these files which are required for the current request?

Answer (score 1):

I think Mono does follow what Microsoft does in .NET,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx

See "Compilation Dependencies" section.

> When the first request is made to an application, ASP.NET compiles files in a specific order

If your top items require that assembly, Mono should search for it on first request.

Comment: usual behaviour of MS.NET is to just ignore those DLLs which can't be loaded - so the application can still work as long as it doesn't try to use the invalid DLL

Comment: so, requested behviour would be to ignore errors when trying to load assemblies which can't be loaded